# How to prevent interference between high voltage and brushless dc motors

Tags: dc, high-voltage, interference

I am a DIYer without much experience in electronics or electrical. I have a device that has 6 DC brushless motors spinning discs around a cube with plasma inside. The motors are were bought at robotshop with [link to details here](bought at [robotshop](https://ca.robotshop.com/products/12v-159rpm-3333oz-in-brushless-dc-gearmotor). In order to generate the plasma I require high voltage electrodes. This is being done using a generator scavenged from a plasma ball toy. Whenever I turn on the electrodes, some of the motors either stop spinning or stutter. Without the high voltage turned on they spin just fine so there is interference that I need to prevent.

I tried putting the high voltage generators inside a shielded box but to no avail. The high voltage that is present and required at the electrode is causing the interference. I’m looking for ideas on how to solve this problem. My ideas are:

- Somehow shield the motors. I have no idea how or whether this is possible.
- Move the motors away from the plasma and high voltage and connect them to a long flexible shaft that can spin the discs. I searched for long flexible shafts that can connect the D shaft of the motors but didn't find any great candidates.

Any ideas or help with the ones I have would be very appreciated!

Comment: Does the motors run with Hall effect sensors? How is the high voltage generated? What’s shared between the motor drives and the HV generation?